# simpler alternative to Dovecot for receiving emails on Centos 8

Tags: email, smtp, imap

We want to receive emails on our server, so when we setup MX DNS record, the emails sent to that domain could be seen on the server

I wonder if there is any simpler alternative to Dovecot for receiving emails on Centos 8, i mean by simpler a script that we can setup with one command or two

Comment: Hi, We want to receive emails on our server, so when we setup MX DNS record, the emails sent to that domain could be seen on the server

Comment: Install exim or postfix. Tell it your domain. Job done. Dovecot is an IMAP server, not an MTA